# Duplicate processes launched via shell script

Tags: java, bash, shell

I am using following shell script to launch a java daemon process (the command is launched via root user):

```
 #!/bin/sh
 sudo -u postfix CONFIG_LOCATION=/mnt/custom java -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=10020 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Djava.util.logging.config.file=${PresentWorkingDirectory}/logging.properties -cp "${ExecutableJar}:${PresentWorkingDirectory}${ClassPath}" com.x.y.filter <&- 1>/dev/null 2>&1 &
```

this is resulting in launching of the two running processes and I am seeing following records in the 'ps -f -All' output:

```
4 S root     24250     1  0  82   0 - 26247 -      20:33 pts/1    00:00:00 sudo -u postfix CONFIG_LOCATION=/mnt/custom java -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=10020 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Djava.util.logging.config.file=${PresentWorkingDirectory}/logging.properties -cp "${ExecutableJar}:${PresentWorkingDirectory}${ClassPath}" com.x.y.filter <&- 1>/dev/null 2>&1 &
4 S postfix  24252 24250 47  82   0 - 364460 184466 20:33 pts/1   00:00:31 java -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=10020 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Djava.util.logging.config.file=${PresentWorkingDirectory}/logging.properties -cp "${ExecutableJar}:${PresentWorkingDirectory}${ClassPath}" com.x.y.filter <&- 1>/dev/null 2>&1 &
```

I am unable to understand why two processes are launched?

while I intend to run only one process and my shell script too is launching only one process.

Can somebody please explain the above observation?

What needs to be done to correct this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is expected behaviour. You are calling `sudo`, which is a process. This process will change it's user to `postfix`, then call `java` - another process.

If `sudo` used `exec` (so that there was only one process used for that command), then `java` would be able to run things it shouldn't (because the `java` binary would replace the `sudo` one in memory, and so have all the privileges the `sudo` one has), which would probably be a bad idea.

Note that the `sudo` binary won't be doing anything: it'll just be waiting for `java` to terminate before doing it's own cleanups.

One of the key things to understand is that `sudo` is not a magic system utility, it's just a normal application that as a `setuid` bit. This means, the `sudo` binary is allowed to change it's runtime user-uid. Once you see this, you begin to understand how `sudo` works and why you get two processes.